# Hbase Schema/Rowkey design for browse data?

Tags: hbase

We are planning to use HBase in one of our projects.

We are getting some browse information from our internal systems, the data format is below.

Our requirement is we have to develop 3 different types of searches

1. D IP + Date Range( Start date and End date )
2. S IP + Date Range( Start date and End date )
3. URL  + Date Range( Start date and End date )

I am thinking to create 3 HBase tables like

1. Row key as DestinationIP + DateTime
2. Row key as SourceIP + DateTime
3. Row key as URL + DateTime

If I go with the above approach it will cost us lot of space to store this data.

```
S IP            DateTime       Method URL        - ResponseCode - D IP -
176.204.134.111 20140421093842 GET    http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/adview?ai=CAbmt4K5UU47XB5GS8wPOi4C4CKH1-ZwCkbiU7inAjbcBEAEgptSKH1D0-ev7B2CRdsgBAakC4V3k_lZFkj6oAwHIA4oEqgSQAU_QtfygurroekV-h5dYCoVP70qKDV1sAkiI60NNZiQ1wICQkqb5XMC3TllLKrhD0KxX0kb9-LnGkCDTqGmDE3Do-UdLGIyluqQ7MwoAcuTJMUajYKOflKPd2ZDj6RlKUAI9pbdkb96-k-XTVpON9rjUM2vUkvjwW3BwSfQk656GjoyUcEwsjwWId7p7obHcTsAEqf_DzQKSBQQIBBgBkgUECAUYBJAGAdgGAoAHueeCC5gHAQ&sigh=7zrG0DRVvMA 0 TCP_MISS/200 - 173.194.66.155 -  0
2.50.165.129    20140421093842 GET    http://www.alquds.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/1217.jpg 0 TCP_MISS/200 - 46.165.251.78 -  0
```

What is a good schema design for these above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/), which is optimized for the storage of small key-value time series data.

Even if you don't choose to use it, definitely read [this slide deck](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/4-opentsdb-hbasecon) discussing the schema design decisions that went into it.

Comment: Our data is not a time series data.Here, we are getting billions of rows with Source IP,Destination IP,URL(upto 2000Char),Datatime.We want to develope 3 searchs based on 1.) Source IP+DateTime AND 2.) Destination IP+Date time AND 3.) URL+Date Time.This OpenTSDB design is not helping us in any ways.

Comment: The fact that you are recording and querying by timestamps suggests to me that it is time series data, even if you do not choose to view it that way.  Either way, take a look at OpenTSDB: from what you have told me it still sounds like a good fit.

Comment: My URL column length is around 2000 Characters, is it ok if I make my URL + Timestamp as ROWKEY? Or will it occupy more space and performance will be decreased?
Because everywhere in Hbase, documentation they are suggesting to keep the ROWKEY as small as possible.
Please suggest.

Comment: Put the url first in the row key, and use the prefix data block encoder (`DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'PREFIX'` in hbase shell.)